# Selecting adjacent rows in an SQL query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, postgresql, optimization

The following is a problem which is not well-suited to an RDBMS, I think, but that is what I've got deal with.

I am trying to write a tool to search through logs stored in a database.
Some rows might be:

```
Time             | ID | Object | Description 
2012-01-01 13:37 | 1  | 1      | Something happened
2012-01-01 13:39 | 2  | 2      | Something else happened
2012-01-01 13:50 | 3  | 2      | Bad
2012-01-01 14:08 | 4  | 1      | Good
2012-01-01 14:27 | 5  | 1      | Bad
2012-01-01 14:30 | 6  | 2      | Good
```

Object is a foreign key. In practice, Time will increase with ID but that is not an actual constraint. In reality there are more fields. It's a Postgres database - I'd like to be able to support SQLite as well but am aware this may well be impossible.

Now, I want to be able to run a query for, say, all Bad events that happened to Object 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Object = 2 AND Description = 'Bad';
```

But it would often be useful to see some lines of context around the results - just as with the `-C` option to `grep` is very useful when searching through text logs.
For the above query, if we wanted one line of context either side, we would want rows 2 and 6 in addition to row 3.

If the original query returned multiple rows, more context would need to be retrieved.
Notice that the context is not retrieved from the events associated with Object 1; we eliminate only the restriction on the Description.
Also, the order involved, and hence what determines what is adjacent to what, is that induced by the Time field.

This specifies what I want to achieve, but the database concerned is fairly big, at least in comparison to the power of the machine it's running on.

The most often cited solution for getting adjacent rows requires you to run one extra query per result in what I'll call the base query; this is no good because that might be thousands of queries.

My current least bad solution is to run a query to retrieved the IDs of all possible rows that could be context - in the above example, that would be a search for all rows relating to Object 2. Then I get the IDs matching the base query, expand (using the list of all possible IDs) to a list of IDs of rows matching the base query or in context, then finally retrieve the data for those IDs.
This works, but is inelegant and slow.
It is especially slow when using the tool from a remote computer, as that initial list of IDs can be very large, and retrieving it and then just transmitting it over the internet can be inordinate.

Another solution I have tried is using a subquery or view that computes the "buffer sequence" of the rows.
Here's what the table looks like with this field added:

```
Time             | ID | Sequence | Object | Description 
2012-01-01 13:37 | 1  | 1        | 1      | Something happened
2012-01-01 13:39 | 2  | 1        | 2      | Something else happened
2012-01-01 13:50 | 3  | 2        | 2      | Bad
2012-01-01 14:08 | 4  | 2        | 1      | Good
2012-01-01 14:27 | 5  | 3        | 1      | Bad
2012-01-01 14:30 | 6  | 3        | 2      | Good
```

Running the base query on this table then allows you to generate the list of IDs you want by adding or subtracting from the Sequence value.
This eliminates the problem of transferring loads of rows over the wire, but now the database has to run this complicated subquery, and it's unacceptably slow, especially on the first run - given the use-case, queries are sporadic and caching is not very effective.

If I were in charge of the schema I'd probably just store this field there in the database, but I'm not, so any suggestions for improvements are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: "adjacency" is an abstract construct... it requires a specific sort in order to be meaningful. Do you mean "time stamps immediately preceeding and following?" How do you break ties? 
In any case you're probably looking at a function to assign row numbers and then you want to `JOIN` on that value +/- 1

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18291217/2589202)

Comment: What database are you using?  SQLite or Postgres?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Postgres, but support SQLite is a bonus.

Comment: @paqogomez correct me if I'm wrong, but that answer seems not to work nicely with a WHERE clause - you only get the next/previous ID of a row within that query. Maybe it's doable with a second query, though.

Comment: FishFace, no, @Matthew's answer is correct.  Windowing will do this for you easily.  It is not supported in SQLite however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select adjacent rows to an arbitrary row (in sql or postgresql)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672283/how-can-i-select-adjacent-rows-to-an-arbitrary-row-in-sql-or-postgresql)

Comment: @feetwet that answer does not address how to efficiently perform the query when you are interested in context around multiple rows.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `ROW_NUMBER` windowing function

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Adjacency is an abstract construct and relies on an explicit sort (or `PARTITION OVER`) ... do you mean the one with the preceeding time stamp?

Decide how you decide on what sort of "adjacent" you want, then get `ROW_NUMBER` over that criteria.

Once you have that you would just `JOIN` each row on the item having `ROW_NUMBER` +/- 1

Comment: no need for the join LEAD and LAG do this (also on the reference link)

Comment: @ConradFrix Excellent point. I didn't realize that `LEAD` and `LAG` were in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with sqlite

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*
  FROM  (SELECT * FROM t WHERE object=2 AND description='Bad') t1
      JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM t WHERE object=2) t2
      ON t1.id = t2.id OR
        t2.id IN (SELECT id FROM t WHERE object=2 AND t.time<t1.time ORDER BY t.time DESC LIMIT 1) OR
        t2.id IN (SELECT id FROM t WHERE object=2 AND t.time>t1.time ORDER BY t.time ASC  LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY t2.time
;
```

Change the limit values ​​by more context